# How to stop a service in Windows 10 Pro 1903 with powershell

Tags: powershell

In Powershell I would like to stop a service:

```
Stop-Service -Name "StateRepository" -Force
```

The service won't stop.  It doesn't make any difference how long I wait.  I'm signed on with the user Administrator in Windows 10 Pro 1903. I don't get any errors.  When I look in services.msc the service is not stopped.

Comment: But what's the state? If it's "Stopping", the service is just not listening to you and the process will have to be forcibly killed. If it's "Running", the request to stop the service either never arrived in the first place, or it stopped but was immediately started again (you can check if this is the case by consulting the event log, the Service Control Manager will log when services stop/start).

Comment: Nothing is logged in EventViewer.  Including the Windows Powershell Event log.

Comment: Curious what happens if you try to stop it using services.msc. The above works fine on my 1809 build- I don't have a 1903 machine on hand.

Comment: It works for me.  Unless it's doing something?

Answer (score 2):

If `Stop-Service -Force` isn't working, I'm not sure what's going on here. However, you can use WMI/CIM to get the current PID of the service and kill it that way (note that this can be an unsafe operation):

```
$service = Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "StateRepository" } | Select -First 1 Name, ProcessId
Write-Warning "Killing process $($service.ProcessId) for service $($service.Name)"
Stop-Process -Force $service.ProcessId
```

This said, it's always better to look into why a service won't stop, as this technique would be more of a last resort.

Comment: Worse, if the service is configured to recover by restarting, the SCM will consider a forcible kill a problem that warrants a restart. So if this doesn't work you may have to go for the nuclear option of setting the startup state to "disabled", even if just temporarily.

Comment: I had the next line of the script to disable the service which also failed.  Set-Service -Name "StateRepository" -StartupType Disabled   When I tried to disable the service manually it won't accept it.  At first I thought it was because it wasn't stopped.  I did stop it manually before I tried to disable it manually.

Comment: @Docfxit: the "State Repository Service" appears to be one that has had its permissions manually adjusted so even administrators can't change the startup state (by default). You can override this using `sc.exe sdset`, but this is pretty advanced stuff and prone to getting changed again with the next Windows update. When MS messes with the security descriptors they really do want you to back off, lest you put the system in a state they don't want to support.

Comment: I found the only user that has full control of the service is Trustedinstaller.  I tried to get control of it with <Path>\subinacl /service StateRepository /grant=Administrator=TOP  I get Access Denined

Comment: If you *really* need to stop/alter this service you could always do so from a SYSTEM console. Either run Powershell as SYSTEM from Task Scheduler (should launch Powershell in the foreground) or you can use `psexec` to launch Powershell as SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

In order for stop and start to work, you have to supply the actual service object.

If found this works well:

```
Stop-Service -Force $(Get-Service -Name "[regex]*" | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne "Stopped"}) 
Start-Service $(Get-Service -Name "[regex]*" | Where-Object {$_.StartType -eq "Automatic"})
```

`[regex]` just indicating a pattern for the name of the service.

But we are not actually using the name as a criteria to stop the service. Rather we use the name to get the list of services, and then the service itself is used as the input to both stop and start. Also that give us finer control over which services we query. As in using `Status` and `StartType`.
And don't forget to run powershell as admin.